# shh connect to home router

Tags: ssh, router

I am trying to ssh to my home router from local network, to explore it's internals.

```
shh myaccount@192.168.1.1
```

returns an error:

```
Unable to negotiate with 192.168.1.1 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

To fix it, I ssh with -o option:

```
ssh -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 myaccount@192.168.1.1 -v
```

At first, ssh hangs for around 5 minutes and than quits.

```
ssh -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 myaccount@192.168.1.1 -v

OpenSSH_7.3p1-hpn14v11, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /opt/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3p1-hpn14v11
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_0.46
debug1: no match: dropbear_0.46
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.1:22 as 'myaccount'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: AUTH STATE IS 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is '3des-cbc'
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: 3des-cbc MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is '3des-cbc'
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: 3des-cbc MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:longstringhere(omitted by me)
debug1: Host '192.168.1.1' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/mainuser/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password




I type in password here. It follows a 5min delay with no messages on screen, and after that it outputs this: 



debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.1 ([192.168.1.1]:22).
debug1: Final hpn_buffer_size = 2097152
debug1: HPN Disabled: 0, HPN Buffer Size: 2097152
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Enabled Dynamic Window Scaling
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 192.168.1.1 closed by remote host.
Connection to 192.168.1.1 closed.
Transferred: sent 2256, received 744 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 5815826.6, received 1917985.4
debug1: Exit status -1
```

What is going on? I don't see any error message. This is my first time trying to ssh to home router, so it might not be possible at all. Whats your experience with ssh-ing to home routers?

```
-vvv outout

 ssh -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 myaccount@192.168.1.1 -vvv
OpenSSH_7.3p1-hpn14v11, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /opt/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "192.168.1.1" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3p1-hpn14v11
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_0.46
debug1: no match: dropbear_0.46
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.1:22 as 'myaccount'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/mainuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.1
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: AUTH STATE IS 0
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: 3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: 3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is '3des-cbc'
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: 3des-cbc MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: REQUESTED ENC.NAME is '3des-cbc'
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: 3des-cbc MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug2: bits set: 502/1024
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:verylongstring(omitted by me)
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/mainuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/mainuser/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.1
debug1: Host '192.168.1.1' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/mainuser/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug2: bits set: 526/1024
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fb137407a10)
debug2: key: /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/mainuser/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
myaccount@192.168.1.1's password: 

waiting here

debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.1 ([192.168.1.1]:22).
debug1: Final hpn_buffer_size = 2097152
debug1: HPN Disabled: 0, HPN Buffer Size: 2097152
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Enabled Dynamic Window Scaling
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t3 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cc -1)

Connection to 192.168.1.1 closed by remote host.
Connection to 192.168.1.1 closed.
Transferred: sent 2256, received 744 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4538297.3, received 1496672.5
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Comment: Is it hanging at _pledge: network_? If so, search for that. There's been several questions about that specific message, and there are a number of things you can check.

Comment: nope, it hangs after I type in password with no messages on screen. After some time, it outputs what I pasted.

Comment: Update your post to include the output before you enter the password, too.

Comment: I added an update.

Comment: No obvious error. Try increasing the verbosity of the debug messages (_-vvv_ option) to see if it tells you more.